# Set Idle Time in Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: 12.04, server, power-management, shutdown

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 Server and am looking for away for get the server to suspend after an idle time. When using the desktop version I could use the Gnome powersaving tool to specify the idle time. As I have no GUI on the server is there a way to set the server idle time via the commandline/config file?

I will send the server a wake-on-lan packet to wake it up, if it is suspended and I need to use it.

Comment: You are not supposed to auto suspend a server. What do you want to achieve? The server will not provide any services while in suspend.

Comment: My server is not always in use. I would like it to suspend when it is idle. I will send it a wake-on-lan when I need to wake it up.

Answer (score 2):

OK, there is the hibernate program, which can send your computer to suspend or hibernate from commandline. Determine if your computer is "idle" is going to be trickier.

On a graphical desktop you would use mouse and keyboard input. Obviously in this scenario this is out of the question.

You should start by writing a shellscript, doing some custom idle checks. You can call this script via a cron job every 5 minutes or so.

You could consider your server idle, if no users are logged in (check this with `who`) or if there are no network connections in use (check with `netstat`) or if the cpu load is low (check for example with `top -n 1 -b`). You will have to find your own heuristics.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I would have assumed that the checks done by the gnome powersaving tool would be "available" somewhere. Seems a little unnecessary to roll your own scripts when there are standard programs that do the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately the checks done by the gnome powersaving tool do realy just refer to the input devices directly attached to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to System>Preferences>Screensaver you can set the idle time there. Just set the preferred time on the bar! Plus if you want to set the picture it's on the same menu.

Jago Gardiner

Comment: I am running the "server" version of Ubuntu which does not have a GUI/Gnome.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that.